# v$logmnr_contents with username as unknown

Tags: oracle-10g

I applied logminer to find who deleted a lot of rows in one table. View v$logmnr_contents give me details of that operation. Unfortunately, minimum supplemental logging was not active when archived redo logs were generated, and when I query v$logmnr_contents, I found columns "username" and "session_info" as "unknown".

Would be there any chance to deduce what user did that operation? Maybe using timestamp to determine what users were logged at that time? Or using column Log_ID?

Comment: Have you looked in `v$active_session_history` (if you're licensed to use ASH) to see if you can see the SQL involved? If the DB hasn't been restarted & the query was recent, the SQL will still be in `v$sql` and `v$sqltext` on the Db the operation occurred on.

Comment: Yes, I have view v$active_session_history with columns session_id, session_serial#, user_id, sql_id ... but in view v$logmnr_contents columns session# and serial# are empty.

Comment: Right - and you know the SQL that was executed? Look for a piece of it `select sql_id, sql_text from v$sql where lower(sql_text) like '%a piece of the query in lowercase%';` on the live database (get the `sql_id`), then you can look in `v$active_session_history` in the live database.